# Set Fragment height programmatically according to existing elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Pre:

- I am extending the relativelayout class and inflating the below reduced xml sample
- I am adding the fragment programmatically in the container layout "fragment_container"

What I want to achieve is to add a fragment in a layout-container (in this case fragment_container) where the height is already ruled by the three textviews

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:text="New Text 2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="New Text 3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

To set the height of the fragment programmatically I am doing this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (!hasFocus) return;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = fragment.getView().getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    params.width = getMeasuredWidth();
    fragment.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

This solution works sometimes (sometimes getMeasuredHeight returns 0 && getMeasuredWidth returns 0), so it's not the correct solution.

Is this a problem that can be solved through the use of the xml only?

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are stacking the views vertically, isn't it better to use LinearLayout with a vertical orientation, and give each view a proper weight (0 for height, and proper value for weight)?

Comment: It's not about the number of textviews. Imagine to solve the same problem with a single textview

Comment: you can still do it with a weight. Let's say the maximum weight is 1. If you set .5 weight for the fragment, it will always take half of the screen and you can share the rest .5 with the rest of the views.

Comment: The problem is another.the height is already ruled by the textview. the fragment has to be on the background and has to fit the space created by view(s).